# How to move/seek long forward/backward using shortcuts in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I have Audacity 2.1 on Osx.

I want to move cursor forward/backward for one second with a single shortcut.

I found that there is a shortcut named "Long seek right during playback". It's default keybinding is Shift+Right. But pushing these buttons makes a audio selection. I changed the shortcut to some other bindings but they didn't work.

Is this the right command to move forward/backward in long steps? If so, I guess there is probably some error in my installation.

Answer (score 3):

There are Cursor Short Jump Left, Cursor Short Jump Right, Cursor Long Jump Left and Cursor Long Jump Right commands, which are assigned to comma (,) and period (.) keys by default. They can be changed in Preferences/Keyboard.

- **Comma**: 1s left
- **Period**: 1s right
- **Shift + Comma**: 15s left
- **Shift + Period** 15s right

Shortcut info found in [Audacity 2.1.0 Guide](http://vip.chowo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/jaws/Audacity-2.1.0-Guide.html#moving-the-cursor).

Comment: You should accept this answer if it works.